# XFCE - Run a shortcut as root, without password

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, root, xfce

I use XFCE which doesn't support the keyboard backlight control keys on my laptop.

I found a script (`/etc/acpi/asus-keyboard-backlight.sh`) that can control it, but I need to run it as root.

I don't want to enter my root password every time I change the keyboard backlight.

How can I configure a keyboard shortcut so that it runs as root without asking for my password ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run it with `sudo`, after having run `visudo` to add `YOURUSER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` which will stop `sudo` from prompting your user for passwords.

Comment: I would like to recommend to allow access to a specific script only via visudo. Giving the entire user "NOPASSWD:ALL" is a really bad idea, because the root password will never be checked when running any script.

Answer (score 1):

Write a small C program that calls Bash to run the script. You compile this program and give it an `suid` bit so that it will run Bash (and hence the script)  as root.

Here's an example of said wrapper:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *bin = "/bin/bash";
    const chrar *script = "/tmp/myscrypt.sh";
    char *const argv[] = {bin, script, NULL};
    char *const env[] = {"SHELL=/bin/bash", 
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "HOME=/root", "LOGNAME=root", "_=/usr/bin/env", NULL};

    execve(bin, argv, env);

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that this runs the script *as root*, including believing that the root is `/root`. If you don't want that, modify the wrapper.

So, once you compile it, all you're left with is giving it an `suid` bit.

```
gcc wrapper.c -o wrapper
chown root wrapper
chmod u+wrxs,g+rx,o-wrx wrapper
```

If you `ls -l`, the permissions will look like so:

```
-rwsr-x--- 1 root group [snip] wrapper
```

This means that only user in the group `group` will be able to run this wrapper. And when they do, the `s` in will mean that their effective user ID will be 0.

If you are doing this is a shared environment where many users belong to the same group, you can create a special group only for this file and add only your user into this group. For instance, maybe you login with LDAP and all users belong to the group "Domain Users". You can create a local group called, say, "JulieOnly" and add only your user into this group. Then you `chown` the wrapper to `root:JulieOnly`.

Comment: After launching the wrapper, I still get a "permission denied" error when the script in /etc/acpi tries to change the backlight settings.

Comment: Post the contents of the script in your question. And run the wraper in the terminal. Add a `uid` command in the script for double-checkig. If possible, comment here the exact error message you get after running the wrapper.